# SQL Server Management Studio - Actual Execution Plan - Actual Row Size and Actual Data Size

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am looking at an actual execution plan in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio v 17.9.1 and I can't see a lot of actual values to compare against the estimates.

For example, we have a connector which holds the following data:

[image]

I can see the Estimate Row and Data Size, but where is their actual size? Is there a way to see this information?

Same question for actual CPU, I/O, number of executions and so on.

**Update:** MS SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I can see the Estimate Row and Data Size, but where is their actual
>   size? Is there a way to see this information?

As commented by @Randi Vertongen I use SQL Sentry Plan explorer to see `actual data size` if I need. This is a free tool you can download (without even giving out your email address).

[Plan Explorer Installation & Overview](https://docs.sentryone.com/help/plan-explorer-installation)

Here is an example of that data you are looking for in plan explorer.

[image]

As far as `actual number of rows` and `number of rows read` is available in SSMS tool tip or properties. Here is an example.

[image]

> Same question for actual CPU, I/O, number of executions and so on.

For CPU and I/O you can right click individual operator and see it in properties or look at xml.  If you right click the leftmost node and see it's properties you will total use of total cpu and  memory grant details. Number of execution is also available in SSMS. See picture above.

Following is an example of overall cpu, time and memory grant information:

[image]

Following is an example of looking at details per operator. This will vary depending on the type of operator. This output is from a sort operator.

[image]

Here is a partial list of when some of these features were added and back ported to older versions.

[image]

Overall plan explorer is a far better tool to look at execution plan and many data professionals use it everyday.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I'm afraid there is no information in the SSMS regarding actual CPU and I/O, nor in the operator's properties, nor in the execution plan XML. Maybe I am looking in the wrong place. Could you please provide a screenshot of the area where you can see this information?

Comment: @spektro37 - this information hasn't always been there. It is a relatively recent enhancement, presumably your version of SQL Server doesn't have it

Comment: @MartinSmith - I believe you are right.

Comment: @SqlWorldWide - thank you for the detailed answer, it is much appreciated.